# Python subprocess, how to pass a list?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to run a cmd through subprocess and pass it a list of arguments, one argument being a list that contains additional arguments. How can I pass this to subprocess?

Example:

```
my_list = ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3']
subprocess.run(["./some.sh", "--flag", "some_arg", "--another_flag", my_list ])
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either use `*` to unpack the list:

```
subprocess.run(["./some.sh", "--flag", "some_arg", "--another_flag", *my_list])
```

Or concatenate the two lists together with `+`:

```
subprocess.run(["./some.sh", "--flag", "some_arg", "--another_flag"] + my_list)
```

`+` will only work on lists (not generators, for example).

The "unpacking" behavior of `*` is documented in the official tutorial [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), although it only addresses using it in function calls, not constructing new lists. It works regardless.